# Prevent pressing escape button

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

If I press escape button data will be saved to database. How to prevent user to submit data if user press escape button? Following code is from material ui Dialog component. I tried with e.keyCode === 27. In material ui e.keyCode === 27 is not working. I want to prevent user submitting data if they press escape button.

```
import React from 'react';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import Dialog from '@material-ui/core/Dialog';
import DialogActions from '@material-ui/core/DialogActions';
import DialogContent from '@material-ui/core/DialogContent';
import DialogContentText from '@material-ui/core/DialogContentText';
import DialogTitle from '@material-ui/core/DialogTitle';
import {getCookie} from "../../../../actions/02 user/01 auth"
import { userInfoEdit,createUserProfile } from '../../../../actions/02 user/02 profile';

export default function FormDialog() {
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);
  const[name,setName] = React.useState(null)


  const handleClickOpen = () => {
    setOpen(true);
  };
  const token = getCookie("token")
  const handleClose1 = ()=>{
   setOpen(false)
  }
  const handleClose = async() => {
    setOpen(false);
    await userInfoEdit({name}, token); //api call
   await createUserProfile(token,{name}) // api call
    setName("");
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Button size ="small" variant="outlined" color="primary" onClick={handleClickOpen}>
       Edit
      </Button>
      <Dialog open={open} onClose={handleClose} aria-labelledby="form-dialog-title">
        <DialogTitle id="form-dialog-title">Edit Name</DialogTitle>
        <DialogContent>
          <DialogContentText>
             Edit name
          </DialogContentText>
             <TextField
            autoFocus
            label="Name"
            value={name}
            type="name"
            margin="normal"
            onChange={(e)=>setName(e.target.value)}
            variant="outlined"
            fullWidth
          />
        </DialogContent>
        <DialogActions>
          <Button onClick={handleClose1} color="primary">
            Cancel
          </Button>
          <Button onClick={handleClose} color="primary"
          disabled={name ? name.length <= 6:!name} 
          >
            Submit
          </Button>
        </DialogActions>
      </Dialog>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: If you don't want the hitting of `escape` to close the modal ***and*** save your data then maybe use your other close handler, `onClose={handleClose1}` so the modal just closes. Or you can disable the escape key for the modal via `disableEscapeKeyDown` prop: https://material-ui.com/api/dialog/#props.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why you are giving `handleClose` function for `Submit` and `onClose`. Give separately like below.

```
export default function FormDialog() {


const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);
  const[name,setName] = React.useState(null)


  const handleClickOpen = () => {
    setOpen(true);
  };
  const token = getCookie("token")
  const handleClose1 = ()=>{
   setOpen(false)
  }
  const popupClose = () => {
   setOpen(false);
  }
  const submitHandleClose = async() => {     
    popupClose();  
    await userInfoEdit({name}, token); //api call
   await createUserProfile(token,{name}) // api call
    setName("");
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Button size ="small" variant="outlined" color="primary" onClick={handleClickOpen}>
       Edit
      </Button>
      <Dialog open={open} onClose={popupClose} aria-labelledby="form-dialog-title">
        <DialogTitle id="form-dialog-title">Edit Name</DialogTitle>
        <DialogContent>
          <DialogContentText>
             Edit name
          </DialogContentText>
             <TextField
            autoFocus
            label="Name"
            value={name}
            type="name"
            margin="normal"
            onChange={(e)=>setName(e.target.value)}
            variant="outlined"
            fullWidth
          />
        </DialogContent>
        <DialogActions>
          <Button onClick={popupClose} color="primary">
            Cancel
          </Button>
          <Button onClick={submitHandleClose} color="primary"
          disabled={name ? name.length <= 6:!name} 
          >
            Submit
          </Button>
        </DialogActions>
      </Dialog>
    </div>
  );
}
```